# Create a folder for images from Visual Studio and "Vector iterator not dereferencable" OpenCV 3.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv3.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010, with OpenCV 3.0.

The following code tries to extract the patches of a sequence of images in order to obtain some blobs of the same dimension.

Firstly, I have tried to create a folder where to save the different images, but I can't:

> string folderCreateCommand = "mkdir " + pathNamePatchBig;
>   system(folderCreateCommand.c_str());

Secondly, it appears the error "Debug Assertion Failed" Vector iterator not dereferencable" after the preincrement of the iterator and I do not know why.

Any thoughts on this?

```
            vector<vector<Point > >::iterator itc=contours.begin();

            while (itc!=contours.end()) {   

                if (itc->size() < cmin || itc->size() > cmax){
                    itc= contours.erase(itc);
                }
                else{

                        std::vector<cv::Point> pts = *itc;
                        cv::Mat pointsMatrix = cv::Mat(pts);
                        cv::Scalar color( 0, 255, 0 );
                        cv::Rect r0= cv::boundingRect(pointsMatrix);
                        cv::rectangle(result,r0,color,2);
                        int patch = 0;
                        string pathNamePatchBig = fileNameRootBig;
                        cv::Mat croppedImageBig = resampledImage(r0).clone();                                                       

                        if ((r0.width>=PatchWidth)&&(r0.height>=PatchHeight)/*&&((frameNumber == 22)||(frameNumber == 157)
                            ||(frameNumber == 239))*/){

                            string fileNamePatchBig = pathNamePatchBig;
                            fileNamePatchBig.append(".jpg");
                            imwrite(fileNamePatchBig,croppedImageBig);

                            //Create the folder
                            string folderCreateCommand = "mkdir " + pathNamePatchBig;
                            system(folderCreateCommand.c_str());

                            int y = r0.y;
                            int initialX = r0.x;
                            int x = initialX;
                            int finalX = r0.x + r0.width;
                            int finalY = r0.y + r0.height;
                            r0.width = PatchWidth;
                            r0.height = PatchHeight;
                            bool cropping = true;
                            while ( (y + PatchHeight)<finalY){

                                string fileName = "";
                                fileName.append(pathNamePatchBig);
                                fileName.append("/");
                                fileName.append(fileNameRootSmall);
                                r0.x = x;
                                r0.y = y;
                                cv::Mat croppedImage = resampledImage(r0).clone();
                                stringstream ss2;
                                ss2 << patch;
                                string patchStr = ss2.str();
                                fileName.append("-");
                                fileName.append(patchStr);
                                fileName.append(".jpg");

                                stringstream ss3;
                                ss3<<fileName;
                                string fullPath = ss3.str();
                                ss3.str("");

                                bool exito = imwrite(fullPath.c_str(),croppedImage);
                                if(!exito){//if not success, break loop
                                    cout << "ERROR: Cannot write the frame into the folder" << endl;
                                    break;
                                }

                                x += shift;
                                if ((x + PatchWidth)>finalX){
                                    y += shift;
                                    x = initialX; 
                                }
                                patch++;

                            }

                        }

                        ++itc;
                    }
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please narrow down the code to the minimum amount necessary to reproduce the issue. See how to do a [mcve]

Comment: Ok @Miki, I have just modified the code, I think now it is right.